# Read Id of last inserted

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been through everything for a couple weeks now only to find statements working at the database level. Below is my code and I feel that I am very near the answer but keep getting `-1` returned from `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. `Customer_Name` is saving to the table just fine along with the auto increment. I just need the `Customer_ID` so that I can place it in the `Customer_Address` table for the one to many identification of the address to the customer.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
if (customer_ID == "")
{
    // add new customer
    string SQL = "INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_Name) VALUES (@customer_Name)";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@customer_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = customer_Name;

    // get last inserted Customer_ID
    string SQL_customerId = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand_customerId = new SqlCommand(SQL_customerId, sqlConnection);

    sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCommand_customerId.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // string SQL_ = "SELECT Customer_ID FROM Customer";
    // SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConnection);
    // int maxId = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)?

Comment: I have studied so much that it would seem that Scope Identity() is the strongest method of getting the ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the SCOPE_IDENTITY within the same transaction as your insert. The following should help you.

```
string SQL = "INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_Name) VALUES (@customer_Name); SELECT Customer_Id FROM Customer WHERE Customer_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@customer_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = customer_Name;
sqlConnection.Open();
int id = (int) sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: thanks Jason, I know have the ID in a string so I can move on.  this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

try something like this.. 
Output clause will help you to get the inserted value and with that we can insert into another temp or physical table. This is just an idea to your question

```
CREATE TABLE customer
  (
     id     INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     addres VARCHAR(500)
  )

CREATE TABLE customeraddrs
  (
     custid INT
  )

INSERT INTO customer
output      inserted.id
INTO customeraddrs
VALUES     ('a'),
            ('b')

SELECT *
FROM   customer

SELECT *
FROM   customeraddrs
```

Comment: Pradeep, this is just what I was saying that I am finding.  this does not help but thanks for trying